# how to disable one button when clicked in mat table Angular material

Tags: angular

I have a problem, I have a mat table and inside this table I have a column to display buttons. The problem is that when I click on one button, all of them disable when I only want to disable the one I click...

my .html:

```
<table *ngIf="buildingImageList.length > 0" mat-table [dataSource]="buildingImageList" class="mat-elevation-z8">
<ng-container matColumnDef="buildId">
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Cancel </th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
<button mat-flat-button color="accent" [disabled]="clicked"
(click)="cancelBuildingImage(element.buildId); clicked = true;">
Cancel build
</button>
</td>
</ng-container>
</table>
```

my .ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { BuildingImage } from "../buildingImage.model";
import { BuilderService } from "../../builder.service";
import { SnackMessageService } from "app/main/common/services/snackMessage.service";


@Component({
  selector: "building-images",
  templateUrl: "./building-images.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./building-images.component.scss"]
})
export class BuildingImagesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  buildingImageList: BuildingImage[];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ["tag", "created", "startedBuilding", "finishDate", "buildId"];
  buildingImageErrorMessage: string;
  callLoop: any;
  clicked: boolean;

  constructor(private builderService: BuilderService, private snackMessageService: SnackMessageService) {
    this.buildingImageList = new Array();

    this.clicked = false;
```

Comment: That happens because all buttons have the same variable for the disabled, you could use the row index and when you call `cancelBuildingImage`, you would send a 2nd parameter that would be the row index, with that you could add it to an array or something and the disabled would check if the row id is in the array or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about to translate clicked to an array.

my .ts:

```
clicked  = new Array();

ngOnInit() {
  this.buildingImageList.foreach(el => {
    this.clicked.push(false);
  });
}
```

Then you just need to be aware of which line number you are clicking. For that, you can append let i=index to your for loop (which is matCellDef in matTable).

my.html

```
<table *ngIf="buildingImageList.length > 0" mat-table [dataSource]="buildingImageList" class="mat-elevation-z8">
<ng-container matColumnDef="buildId">
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Cancel </th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i=index">
<button mat-flat-button color="accent" [disabled]="clicked[i]"
(click)="cancelBuildingImage(element.buildId); clicked[i] = true;">
Cancel build
</button>
</td>
</ng-container>
</table>
```